# How to replace a string with another in whole tables in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, procedure

I want to replace a string with another in full database. Assume database name is "A" and it contains 101 tables. I want to change "subhojit" to "jeet" in all table's column if it contains "subhojit".

Is it possible in MySql?
Need to write procedure?
Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
update thetable set thecol = replace(thecol, 'subhojit', 'jeet')
where thecol like '%subhojit%';
```

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Comment: He wants to do that for all tables in his DB.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit rough and ready (exception handling for example). But hopefully you can tidy it up for your own purposes:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `replace_value_in_all_cols`(IN i_schema varchar(250),IN i_fromVal varchar(250),IN i_toVal varchar(250), OUT o_errMessage varchar(250))
BEGIN
ALL_TEXT_COLUMNS : BEGIN

DECLARE noMoreRows boolean;
DECLARE db varchar(250);
DECLARE tbl varchar(250);
DECLARE col varchar(250);

DECLARE allTextCols CURSOR FOR
    select c.table_schema,c.table_name,c.column_name
    from information_schema.columns c
    where c.table_schema = i_schema
    and lower(data_type) in ('char','text','varchar');

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER for SQLEXCEPTION set o_errMessage := "Some error message";
declare continue handler for not found set noMoreRows := true;

open allTextCols;

  UPDATE_LOOP : loop

   fetch allTextCols
   into db,tbl,col;

   if noMoreRows then
    close allTextCols;
    leave UPDATE_LOOP;
   end if;

   SET @update_stmt:=CONCAT("UPDATE ",db,".",tbl," SET ",col," = replace(",col,",'",i_fromVal,"','",i_toVal,"');"); 
  PREPARE update_stmt FROM @update_stmt; 
  EXECUTE update_stmt; 
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE update_stmt;

  end loop UPDATE_LOOP;

 END ALL_TEXT_COLUMNS;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can do something like:

```
call `replace_value_in_all_cols`("A",'subhojit','jeet', @err);
```